# anova.rms problem with rcs() terms

Tags: r, regression, anova

I´m having problem with the anova function in the rms package:

```
require(rms)
getHdata(prostate)

mod1<-cph(Surv(dtime,status!="Alive")~stage+rx+age+wt,data=prostate,x=T,y=T)
mod2<-cph(Surv(dtime,status!="Alive")~stage+rx+rcs(age,4)+wt,data=prostate,x=T,y=T)
anova(mod1)
anova(mod2)
```

-everything works alright, but when I try to compare the models for the impact of non-linearity on age

```
anova(mod1,mod2)
```

I get

```
Error in anova.rms(mod1, mod2) : factor names not in design:  mod2
```

What does this mean? What can I do to circumvent it?

//M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the output of anova(mod2) as one way to assess the significance  but the best answer would be to compare the -2*log(likelihood) statistics. The anova.rms function is not designed to take two model fits. The second and subsequent unnamed arguments are assumed to be names of terms within the model rather than fit objects.

(Note that with `rcs` terms you will not see the sum of individual terms equal the full model chi-square values. I have asked Harrell about this and he says to do the cross-model comparisons "by hand".)

Comment: Thx for clearing the anova thing up. However, also in rms is lrtest --lrtest(mod1,mod2)-- which seems to give me what i want.

Comment: You should write it up and give yourself a check.

Answer (score 0):

This comparison is done using `lrtest` (per Misha's comment).